# Attribute on method doesn't work

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a method with an attribute (in c# library). The problem is that attribute is not call when I call my method. I don't understand why !

My code:

```
[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class RequireAuthorization : System.Attribute
{
    private bool _protected = true;

    public RequireAuthorization(bool protect)
    {
        _protected = protect;
    }
}

public class MyClass(){

    [RequireAuthorization(true)]
    public bool method1(){
       // some actions
    }
}
```

Some idea please?

Comment: Please learn more about attributes before asking such questions. I only can say that attributes can describe some metadata for methods, properties or fields, and this metadata should be read manually using reflection

Comment: And check out the naming Convention. The Class should be named RequireAuthorizationAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are simply metadata and does not perform any sort of pre/post interception of method invocations.

For this to work, you need some interception mechanism, e.g. Post# or dynamic proxies etc.

See http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/security

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are just metadata, they are jitted and part of your codebase, but they don't need to run.

To enforce running your custom Attribute you could use reflection, the following would cause the constructor of your `RequireAuthorization` class to be executed:

```
MemberInfo memberInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("method1");
var attributes = memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);
```