# C# CustomAttribute wouldn't work

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I working on .NET 2.0. Unfortunatelly i couldn't use a newer version.
I try to wrote my owne Attribute providing a simple value.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class testAttribute : Attribute
{
    int b;
    public testAttribute(int a)
    {
        b = a;
        Console.WriteLine("Creating Attribute");
    }
    public testAttribute()
    {
        b = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Creating Attribute");
    }
}

public class MyTestClass
{
    [testAttribute]
    public MyTestClass()
    {
        int a = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("creating serializer 2");
    }

    [testAttribute(2)]
    public void foo(){
        //Type t = this.GetType();
        //testAttribute[] t2 = (testAttribute[])t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(testAttribute), true);
        Console.WriteLine("calling foo");

        object[] attr = typeof(MyTestClass).GetCustomAttributes(true);
        int a = 5;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.
I figured out that example from msdn [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4a92379%28v=vs.80%29.aspx ] and for me this looks very similar.

I also found this: [Attribute on method doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078403/attribute-on-method-doesnt-work) but this is not exactly my problem I think. As you can see I tried out the   recommendation from BrokenGlass but I got an array with dimenson 0 that means there is no Attribute.

Any Suggestions?
Regards Chomp

Comment: What means "does not work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `GetCustomAttributes` for the methods, not the type.

```
object[] attr = typeof(MyTestClass).GetMethod("foo").GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Comment: Consider using `GetConstructor()` for the first one. Also method names are case sensitive.